# Paste the name of the folder a sheet is contained in

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet which is the active sheet, and I would like to paste the name of the folder the excel sheet is contained in into cells in Excel.
Is there a way to do this and if so how?

ie. how can I get the folder that the activeSheet is in? Is there a function called active folder or something?

Comment: thsiworkbook.path

Comment: A sheet is located in a workbook which is located in a folder (if it's not new). You can get the path of the sheet's workbook by using `Dim wbPath As String: wbPath = ActiveSheet.Parent.Path`. Then you could do `Dim wbFolderName As String: wbFolderName = Right(wbPath, Len(wbPath) - InStrRev(wbPath, "\"))`.

Comment: @VBasic2008 I recommend `InStrRev(wbPath, Application.PathSeparator)` so it is platform independent.

Answer (score 1):

### From code

Use **ActiveWorkbook.Path**.  If the active workbook has not been saved, an empty string will be returned.

```
Sub FindFolder()

Dim strFolder As String

    strFolder = ActiveWorkbook.Path

    ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value = strFolder

End Sub
```

### From Formula

Use the **CELL** function to get the full path, file name and sheet name.  Then extract the folder using **LEFT** and **FIND** functions.  If the active workbook has not been saved, a **#VALUE!** will be returned.

```
=LEFT(CELL("filename"),FIND("[",CELL("filename"))-1)
```

Comment: The `FindFolder`-routine could be called from the `Workbook_BeforeSave`-event. That should ensure that the information is up to date. However, I would advocate to use the formula as that is up to date any time.